# Set a string in Android, log the string, Null pointer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a member variable: `String message = null;`

This is an async task with two `Log.d()` statements.

```
private class LoadFromWeb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Ion.with(MyActivity.this,
                "http://example.com/api/?post=1_15_2014&json=1")
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        if (result == null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        JsonObject jsonCustomFields = result
                                .getAsJsonObject("post").getAsJsonObject(
                                        "custom_fields");

                        String jsonMessage = jsonCustomFields
                                .getAsJsonArray("message").get(0)
                                .toString();


                        message = jsonMessage;
                                Log.d("me", message); //Output: "Hello World"


                    }
                });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void arg0) {
        Log.d("me", message); //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

    }
    }
```

I have no idea why it's doing this, and I'm not touching the member variable anywhere else. I'm out of ideas.

The exact error is:

```
01-16 00:31:25.360: E/AndroidRuntime(17807): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

**Update:**

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockListActivity {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    private DatabaseHelper db = null;
    TextView myView;
    String message = null;
```

Comment: where is `String message` declared. messge is null @ `Log.d("me", message);`

Comment: Updated my question to show that String message is declared as a member variable of the class.

Comment: change `String message = null;` to `String message = "";`

Comment: Aren't you creating another async task inside of your `doInBackground` method? So the flow is like that: `doInBackground` is called, inside that a new async task is created with `ION.with`, `doInBackground` returns null. So the code in the inner async task may be executed after everything else.

Comment: Oh man. There goes my whole idea of using ion in doInBackGround. I think that's going to be the solution. I'll check it out now.

Comment: @EGHDK why do you need  `FutureCallback` remove ite. return the result in doInbackground. and log the message in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @Scadge Yep. That was it. If you want to post that as the answer I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating another async task inside of your `doInBackground` method. So the flow is like that: `doInBackground` is called, inside it a new async task is created with `ION.with` (but not necessarily executed at that moment), and `doInBackground` returns null. So the code in the inner async task may be executed after everything else.

Answer (score 1):

[ION](https://github.com/koush/ion) itself a asynchronous network library. Calling `Ion` in a `Asynctask` means you are calling another `Asynctask` inside a `Asynctask`. Thats the problem. If you use  `Log.d("me", message);` before the line `return null;` in `doInBackground` method you also get the NPE.

Dont use `Asynctask` with Ion. Using the following code will do everything required for you

```
Ion.with(MyActivity.this,
                "http://example.com/api/?post=1_15_2014&json=1")
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        if (result == null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        JsonObject jsonCustomFields = result
                                .getAsJsonObject("post").getAsJsonObject(
                                        "custom_fields");

                        String jsonMessage = jsonCustomFields
                                .getAsJsonArray("message").get(0)
                                .toString();


                        message = jsonMessage;
                                Log.d("me", message); //Output: "Hello World"


                    }
                });
```

`onCompleted` in Ion is same as `onPostExecute` of `Asynctask`

Answer (score 0):

While you are using log please define like this you will never get nullpointerexception

```
Log.e("me", "is:"+message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Log.d("me", "value : " +message);
```

even the value null it display log. it will not cause NPE

Answer (score 0):

the string message is set in this line

```
message = jsonMessage;
```

but before this the message is `null`. so if the `result` is `null`in the following line

```
if (result == null) {
    return;
}
```

then it is returned. So in the onPostexecute message is null thus getting the exception.